# Open file uri in phonegap

Tags: cordova

Is it possible in phonegap to open a file uri (file:///mnt/sdcard/test/images.jpeg) with the default phone viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean if the embedded browser can display an image from the phones file system, if so yes thats possible. This is how you could use the camera api for a long time.